# Adding record to Access Database using Visual Basic

Tags: database, vb.net, vb.net-2010

Here is my code for the add button:

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the '_PS_Database___Gawa_ni_arrah___Gamitin_sa_Database_ng_VBDataSet.PS_Tracking_System' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.PS_Tracking_SystemTableAdapter.Fill(Me._PS_Database___Gawa_ni_arrah___Gamitin_sa_Database_ng_VBDataSet.PS_Tracking_System)

End Sub

Private Sub Save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Save.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.PS_Tracking_SystemBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me._PS_Database___Gawa_ni_arrah___Gamitin_sa_Database_ng_VBDataSet)
    MsgBox("Record Details Saved Successfully")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.PS_Tracking_SystemTableAdapter.Insert(IDTextBox.Text, Reference_NumberTextBox.Text, APP_Reference_NumberTextBox.Text, End_User___Project_Management_OfficeTextBox.Text, Package_Lot_Item_ClusterTextBox.Text, ABCTextBox.Text, Funding_SourceTextBox.Text, BAC_Secretariat_ResponsibleTextBox.Text, Personnel_in_ChargeTextBox.Text, Project_NumberTextBox.Text, Type_of_ProcurementTextBox.Text, Method_of_PrpcurementTextBox.Text, Cost_of_Bidding_DocumentsTextBox.Text, Notice_of_Pre_Bid_ConferenceTextBox.Text, Number_of_Bid_Bulletin_IssuedTextBox.Text, Remarks_on_Post_QualificationTextBox.Text, Contract_AmountTextBox.Text, Name_of_Supplier_Provider_ConstructorTextBox.Text, RemarksTextBox.Text, Released_toTextBox.Text, TextBox1.Text)
    Me.PS_Tracking_SystemTableAdapter.Fill(Me._PS_Database___Gawa_ni_arrah___Gamitin_sa_Database_ng_VBDataSet.PS_Tracking_System)
    MsgBox("Record Added Successfully")
    IDTextBox.Text = ""
    Reference_NumberTextBox.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

End Class

**Sample Error message is:**

Error   1   Argument not specified for parameter '_Contract_Purchase_Oreder_No' of 'Public Overridable Overloads Function Insert(ID As Integer?, Reference_Number As String, APP_Reference_Number As String, _End_User___Project_Management_Office As String, Project_TItle As String, _Package_Lot_Item_Cluster As String, ABC As String, Funding_Source As String, Date_Received_by_PS As String, BAC_Secretariat_Responsible As String, Personnel_in_Charge As String, Project_Number As String, _Pre_Proc_Date As String, Type_of_Procurement As String, Method_of_Prpcurement As String, Date_of_Approval_of_BAC_Resolution_for_AMP As String, Date_of_Advertisement_in_Newspaper As String, Date_of_Posting_in_PhilGEPS As String, Date_of_Posting_in_DepEd_Website_and_Bulletin_Board As String, Cost_of_Bidding_Documents As String, Date_of_Pre_Bid_Conference As String, Notice_of_Pre_Bid_Conference As String, Number_of_Bid_Bulletin_Issued As String, Deadline_of_Submission_and_Opening_of_Bids As String, Date_of_Bid_Evaluation As String, _Deadline_of_Post_Qualification As String, Remarks_on_Post_Qualification As String, Date_of_Preparation_of_RTA As String, Date_of_Approval_of_RTA As String, Date_of_Preparation_of_NOA As String, Date_of_Acceptance_of_NOA As String, _Contract_Purchase_Oreder_No As String, Contract_Amount As String, _Name_of_Supplier_Provider_Constructor As String, Date_of_Preparation_of_NTP As String, Date_of_Acceptance_of_NTP As String, Remarks As String, Other_Document_Particulars As String, Action_Taken As String, Date_Released_from_PS As String, Released_to As String) As Integer'.   C:\Documents and Settings\Jag Flores\Desktop\Jag - Visual Basic Tracking System - LATEST 080414 923AM\WindowsApplication3\Form1.vb  17  9   WindowsApplication3

I'll post a link of my interface for added info.:
Form 1: http://i158.photobucket.com/albums/t118/ajjose/form1.jpg
Form 2: http://i158.photobucket.com/albums/t118/ajjose/form2.jpg

Thanks in advance :/

Comment: **Argument not specified for parameter '_Contract_Purchase_Oreder_No'**

Comment: As an aside, you have way too many parameters in that Insert call.  Create an object that contains those parameters as properties, rewrite the `insert` method to accept the object, populate the object with data, and pass the object instead of all those parameters.

Comment: `Argument not specified for parameter` is from Access and often means a spelling mistake in the SQL somewhere (maybe `Oreder` instead of `Order`?).

Comment: @LukeHoffmann Question sir; Doesn't that error mean that in a function or subroutine, you didn't provide data to pass to a parameter you declared? IE Public Sub  Sampler(byval x as string) and then you called Sampler(), but didn't add any argument? (Should be Sampler("Sample String"))

Comment: @Malky.Kid Yes, I didn't realise this was just a compile error. I was thinking of a runtime error that often comes from Access: `No value given for one or more required parameters`